# Why am I frequently asked to access a cached copy of a particular webpage?

Tags: cache, google-chrome

I moved my WordPress website from `localhost` to a live server, but sometime I am able to access my website and sometime not, it shows:

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not find www.example.com
Access a cached copy of example.com
```

I don't know what is this and how to resolve it. Please give me some guidelines to sort this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error could mean any number of things are going wrong.

- [There are reports](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/T7Alqv2lHCM) that Google Chrome itself shows that error message when it shouldn't sometimes.   This could be the case, especially if it isn't happening with *just* your site.
- Your domain name could be misconfigured or your DNS hosting could be spotty.  [Here are some tools to help with this](http://royal.pingdom.com/2008/06/05/14-useful-and-free-online-tools-for-dns-and-network-troubleshooting/), especially the health test tools.
- Your web server could be non-responsive or slow.  Use a tool or site to test your server.

Chrome may also give a more useful and specific message if you uncheck the "Use a web service to help resolve navigation errors" option under the advanced privacy options.   Also test your web site in other browsers -- they may shed more light on the problem with better error messages.

Comment: thanks stephen, before your answer I was thinking it is some technical issue in my wordpress site...so thanks again